# Анимированное появление скрытого блока при выборе в select

Tags: javascript, анимация, form, html

Есть форма, а в ней выбор услуг(select) и при выборе одной из услуг появляется div с ещё одним select. Так вот сама суть вопроса, как сделать так, чтоб этот div появлялся не резко, а как бы плавно расширялся сам и соответственно расширял всю форму вниз?

```js
function Selected(a) {
  var label = a.value;
  if (label == 3) {
    document.getElementById("docsl").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("docsu").style.display = 'none';
  } else if (label == 1) {
    document.getElementById("docsl").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("docsu").style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("docsl").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("docsu").style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<!--Основной select-->
<select name="service" onChange="Selected(this)">
  <option value="0" selected ></option>
  <option value="1" selected>Услуга 1</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Услуга 2</option>
  <option value="3" selected>Услуга 3</option>
  <option value="4" selected>Услуга 4</option>       
</select>
<!--Один из появляющихся div-->
<div name="docsl" id="docsl" style='display:none;'>
  <div class="label">
    Доп выбор
  </div>
  <div class="field-input">
    <select name="docl" class="input">
      <option value="0" selected></option>
      <option value="1" selected>Доп выбор 1</option>
      <option value="2" selected>Доп выбор 2</option>         
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за помощь, но реализовал иначе. Может кто такой же ноль как и я, вот ему моё решение. Всё оказалось намного проще, чем я думал, просто использовал функции SlideUp и SlideDown. Пример кода:

```
function Selected(a) {
    var label = a.value;
    if (label==3) {
        $(docs_uzi).slideUp("slow");
        $(docs_lazer).slideDown("slow");            
    } else if (label==1) {
        $(docs_lazer).slideUp("slow");
        $(docs_uzi).slideDown("slow");
    }
    else {
        $(docs_lazer).slideUp("slow");
        $(docs_uzi).slideUp("slow"); 
    }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

```css
div
{
  width: 400px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  transition: 1s;
}

div:hover
{
  height: 400px;
}

/* Если конечный размер div-а неизвестен, используйте примерный max-height вместо height */
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: оно бы так хорошо, но при этом div так же резко появляется, но при наведении на него курсора начинает расширятся, а нужно, чтоб плавно расширялся при появлении

Comment: Ну так я привёл код для примера. Измените :hover на свой класс, и добавляйте его, когда нужно показать блок